# Cocoa make WKWebView command + link click open in new window

Tags: macos, cocoa, wkwebview

I'm trying to make WKWebView open a link in a new window/tab when user has the cmd key pressed when clicking on a link, just like in any browser. I couldn't find a native api to do so (or maybe am I just suck at googling). Can anyone give me an idea how I can implement this with no dirty hacks? Did I miss a naive api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a **WKNavigationDelegate**.

In the navigation process, the

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler;
```

method will be called. The WKNavigationAction object has a *modifierFlags* property that tells you whether the cmd key was pressed during the clic.

If it was, then do whatever you wish to open a new window/tab with a new WKWebView and start loading the page from here (I personally send an event with all the info that will be processed later on).

Finally, cancel you current web view navigation by calling

```
decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel) ;
```

Comment: Wow! You sir are my savior. I did not know WKNavigationAction has that flag!